# Avidemux - how to add my site's name to the beggining of the video

Tags: windows

OK, I have Avidemux and I want to add my site's name, description, address and logo to the beginning of my videos. I made a PNG image with these items, and with the same resolution of my videos. But I don't know how to configure how many time it will appear in the screen. I don't want it blinking for only 1/30s. Maybe 1.5/2s. How can I do that?

If there is no way to do that using Avidemux, can you please tell me how I can do this using other open-source video editor (for Windows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easiest software for video composing, but you can find tutorial [here](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=tutorial:create_video_from_still_image_and_from_audio_file), how to achieve what you want.

I advice you to use something with timeline like Windows Movie Maker or Lightworks. So you can see your changes on timeline.

I believe you also can use ffmpeg for that purpose, but it will be more complex.

Comment: I tried this tutorial, but, like it said there, this program doesn't works properly for that purpose... When I try PNG image, the color appears inverted, and when I try JPG, I get a bunch of error windows.

Comment: Like a workaround you can try to invert your PNG image before adding to the composition...

Comment: I'm trying to use Blender. It's free, open-source, and non-linear.

Comment: Blender can be too complex program for beginning....

Comment: I think it's worth a try. GIMP was too complex for me, just after I left Paint, but I learn something more as I need.